# Branching Process and point of ceasing

Tags: probability, probability-theory, branching-rules

Let $(Z_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}_{0}}$ be a branching process. The following generations are distributed with the PMF $p(0)=p(2)=\frac{1}{2}$.

How do I define the distribution of $Z_{3}$ and what is the probability for the extinction of the process?

I started with computing $G(z)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}z^{2}$. How do I continue?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: you continue by writing down the definitions of branching process and PMF and by writing down the relationships between $Z$, $p$, and $G$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generating function of $Z_3$ is $G(G(G(z)))$. Once you compute this function you can write down the distribution of $Z_3$. The extinction probability is obtained by solving the equation $G(z)=z$ which shows that extinction probability  is $1$.

Comment: Thank you for your support. I finally solved the problem! When I compute $G(G(G(z)))$, I get three probabilities which add up to one, so this should be alright.